# How to set a colormap which can give me over 20 distinct colors in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, colormap

I've tried the code below:

```
number = 20
cmap = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
colors = [cmap(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, number)]
```

This can generate a set of colors but not so distinct. In fact the nearest plots have almost the same color. I also tried `'jet'` and `'nipy_spectral'` according to http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html. However they are not so satisfying.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a number of distinct colors using the HLS colorspace, instead of extracting the colors from a matplotlib cmap.

In particular, distinct colors depend on differing hues. Try something like this:

```
from colorsys import hls_to_rgb
import numpy as np 

def get_distinct_colors(n):

    colors = []

    for i in np.arange(0., 360., 360. / n):
        h = i / 360.
        l = (50 + np.random.rand() * 10) / 100.
        s = (90 + np.random.rand() * 10) / 100.
        colors.append(hls_to_rgb(h, l, s))

    return colors
```

Comment: Your solution is better than the matplotlib cmap, but still has some colors that looks almost the same. How to avoid this?